# On ubuntu what are the nvidia drivers that would use wayland and can handle dual monitors?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, 64-bit, nvidia-prime

I have a legion 5 with AMD iGpu and nvidia dGpu. The problem is prime does not work like it should. It does not turn off my dGpu while it is not in use and I can't turn it off.

The only driver that worked is the old 390. It does use wayland, it does use only 8 watts of power, since the dGpu is turned off, there's only one problem.. mutliple display does not work with that driver. So I can't connect my monitor to it.

If i sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-390 and all of it's components and reboot to the installed nvidia-driver-535 it boots with x11, and it won't turn off the dGpu. Which is a problem for me, since I use the laptop at uni and I don't want 2-3 hours of SOT.

Are there any driver that works with AMD + Nvidia Gpus so that it turns off dGpu when I set it to and can handle external displays?